# Pass JS variable across mouseenter event from jquery in angular2 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have trouble witch function below:

```
inactive() { 
        let target = $('.album__item--cover-container');
        var leave:boolean;
        target.mouseleave(function() {
            leave = true;
            console.log("LEAVE MOUSEENTER: ", leave);
        });
        console.log("LEAVE: ", leave);
        if (leave) {
            console.log("LEAVE CONDITION: ", leave);
            this.flyOut = 'inactive';
        }
        console.log(this.flyOut); 
    }
```

I don't know wht log `"LEAVE MOUSEENTER"` is true, and after exit from mouse event log `"LEAVE`" is `undefined`. I can't declate `this.flyOut = true` in this event function. Please someone helop me, and explain why  this behaviour goes that way?

Regards
Greg

Comment: Maybe it is scope issue. Can you use arrow function? targer.mouseleave(() => {...}). And maybe change var to let

Comment: You were right. There was missing .bind(this) assignment, which arrow functions has by default. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is because you are not doing anything inside the callback of the mouse leave event.

This is only run once when `inactive()` is invoked.

```
if (leave) {
    console.log("LEAVE CONDITION: ", leave);
    this.flyOut = 'inactive';
}
```

I'm assuming you are trying to set some state on mouseleave, and you then want to check if `this.flyOut` is inactive?

```
(function ($) {// just some wrapper
    let flyOut = 'inactive'
    const target = $('.album__item--cover-container'); // Use const if you know it wont change
    const check = $('.check-button-class-thing');

    target.mouseleave(function() {
        flyOut = 'inactive'
    });

    target.mouseenter(function() {
        flyOut = 'active'
    });

    check.click(function() {
        console.log(inactive()); // Is it inactive or not
    });

    function inactive() {
        return flyOut === 'inactive' ? true : false;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I'm making assumptions here on your use case but I hope this helps. The code itself is not very useful as it depends on where the `.check-button-class-thing` is nested but its just an example.

Comment: There was missing .bind(this) assignment, which arrow functions has by default, but it could be done by your way also:) Thanks for response!

Answer (score 0):

The

```
if (leave) {
```

is out of the `mouseleave` function callback. So when `inactive()` is called the first time, `leave` has been declared without any default value (it's `undefined`). And the if is called.
It will only be true when the `mouseleave` event is called.